# What is the difference in PHP between DOM nodes and XMLreader->expand() Nodes?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xmlreader

I've rewritten a script that used the PHP DOM functions to iterate through an XML file with a structure like this:

```
<file>
    <record>
        <Source>
            <SourcePlace>
                <Country>Germany</Country>
            </SourcePlace>          
        </Source>
        <Person>
            <Name>
                <firstname>John</firstname>
                <lastname>Doe<lastname>
            </Name>
        </Person>
    </record>
    <record>
    ..
    </record>
</file>
```

I've replaced it with a script that uses XMLreader to find each separate record and turn that into a DOMdocument after which it is iterated through. Iteration was done by checking if the node had a child:

```
function findLeaves($node) {
   echo "nodeType: ".$node->nodeType.", nodeName:". $node->nodeName."\n";
   if($node->hasChildNodes() )  {
       foreach($node->childNodes as $element) {
           findLeaves($element)
       }
   }
   ELSE { <do something with leave> }
}
```

The problem is that the behaviour of the *findLeaves()* function has changed between the two. Under DOM a node without a value (like *Source*) had no #text childnodes. Output of above would be:

````
nodeType:1, nodeName:Source
nodeType:1, nodeName:SourcePlace
nodeType:1, nodeName:Country
nodeType:3, nodeName:#text ```
````

Under XMLreader this becomes:

```
nodeType: 1, nodeName:Source
nodeType: 3, nodeName:#text
nodeType: 1, nodeName:SourcePlace
nodeType: 3, nodeName:#text
nodeType: 1, nodeName:Country
```

I've checked the saveXML() result of the data before entering this function but it seems identical, barring some extra spaces. What could be the reason for the difference?

Code loading the file before the findleaves() function under DOM:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
$xmlDoc->load($file);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
$records = $xpath->query('//record');

foreach($records as $record) {
        foreach ($xpath->query('.//Source', $record) as $source_record) {
            findleaves($source_record);

        }
}
```

Code loading the file before the findleaves() function under XMLreader:

```
$xmlDoc = new XMLReader()
$xmlDoc->open($file)
while ($xmlDoc->read() ) { 
    if ($xmlDoc->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xmlDoc->name == 'record') {         
        $record_node = $xmlDoc->expand();

        $recordDOM = new DomDocument();
        $n = $recordDOM->importNode($record_node,true); 
        $recordDOM->appendChild($n);document        
        $recordDOM->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($recordDOM);      
        $records = $xpath->query('//record'); 

        foreach($records as $record) {
        foreach ($xpath->query('.//Source', $record) as $source_record) {
            findleaves($source_record);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `DOMDocument::$preserveWhiteSpace` affects the load/parse functions. So if you use `XMLReader::expand()` the property of the document has no effect - you do not **load** a XML string into it.

You're using Xpath already. `.//*[not(*) and normalize-space(.) !== ""]` will select element nodes without element children and without any text content (expect white spaces).

Here is an example (including other optimizations):

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<file>
    <record>
        <Source>
            <SourcePlace>
                <Country>Germany</Country>
            </SourcePlace>          
        </Source>
        <Person>
            <Name>
                <firstname>John</firstname>
                <lastname>Doe</lastname>
            </Name>
        </Person>
    </record>
</file>
XML;    

$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('data://text/plain;base64,'.base64_encode($xml));

$document = new DOMDocument();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// find first record
while ($reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'record') {
  continue;
}

while ($reader->localName === 'record') {
  // expand node into prepared document    
  $record = $reader->expand($document);

  // match elements without child elements and empty text content
  // ignore text nodes with only white space
  $expression = './Source//*[not(*) and normalize-space() != ""]';
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression, $record) as $leaf) {
      var_dump($leaf->localName, $leaf->textContent);
  }

  // move to the next record sibling
  $reader->next('record');
}
$reader->close();
```

Output:

```
string(7) "Country"
string(7) "Germany"
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work quite well. Simply requiring all nodes that are leaves is quite elegant.  One questions: what is the importance of the `while ($reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'record') {` part? Doesn’t the next while loop simply start at the first occurrence?

Comment: No, `next()` only looks at following siblings. So you need to use `read()` to find the first node (it looks at descendants).